# XAMPP & C# Socket IPAdress questions

Tags: networking, xampp, c#, sockets

I'm working on a multiplayer game and I'd really like to bring it online.

I'm a bit dumb when it comes to networking so please bear with me as I try to make heads and tails of this.

I have a C# console that functions as a server.

```
        IPAddress.TryParse( "127.0.0.1", out IPAddress iPAddress );
        serverSocket.Bind ( new IPEndPoint ( iPAddress, 5555 ) );
```

And I have the game client

```
        clientSocket.BeginConnect( "127.0.0.1"
                                 , 5555
                                 , new AsyncCallback( ConnectCallback )
                                 , new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                                             , SocketType.Stream
                                             , ProtocolType.Tcp
                                             )
                                 );
```

The game uses an SQL database from XAMPP. While setting it up I discovered you can turn your IP address into a website *of sort*, so now I'm wondering if I can host my game using my public IP address since I'm able to access my local host by entering it into the browser.

I imagine I'd need to forward my games port and change the server and client IPAdress to **my public ip**:5555, am I right in thinking that? It's just things like this are never as easy as they seem so I thought I'd best ask in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's the same kind of TCP connection as used by e.g. HTTP or SSH. When you have a single public IP for the entire LAN, you can use the exact same "port forwarding" mechanism for your game server on custom ports as you would with (e.g.) a web server on port 80.

While testing, keep in mind that connecting to `<public IP>` *from inside the same LAN* is slightly problematic: if it works at all, then it usually works strangely (i.e. your server won't know the real client IP address).

Finally, whether the game server uses SQL is irrelevant. Your client only connects to the game server, but does not need to know anything about what the server does internally. The connection from your server app to the SQL database is internal, and doesn't need to use the public IP address for anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it really lifted my spirits. It might be a bit hasty to ask for further support but when I call `Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint("80.15.80.50", 5555));` I get the error 'The requested address is not valid in its context'.

Comment: False alarm, got it working. Very happy! Now to test it somehow.